# Would my direct knowledge of SharePoint Designer and InfoPath Workflows help me to take on a third party form solution substantially faster?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, infopath, third-party-software

I have used SharePoint Designer and InfoPath for the longest time but I was never fortunate enough to work in an environment that had Nintex, K2, or a third party solution.

Would my direct knowledge of SharePoint Designer and InfoPath Workflows help me to take on a third party solution substantially faster?
I do know that Nintex or K2 or some other third party solution assists in the creation of forms and can make life a lot easier going from SharePoint 2010 to 2013.

What is the learning curve for such a solution? I am about to begin a consultant position that requires it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Would my direct knowledge of SharePoint Designer and InfoPath Workflows help me to take on a third party solution substantially faster?**

Of course, yes, Working with the available SharePoint tools like SharePoint Designer and InfoPath ... etc will help. At least, it provides you a very good knowledge of workflow and forms ...etc concepts,

At the same time that doesn't mean you won't need training on the new tools!
But the time it takes to learn and use the new 3rd party tools will be much less depends on your current SharePoint knowledge in general, the gained skills from using the available SharePoint tools in particular!

And I totally agree that the 3rd party tools are very helpful and make the SharePoint easier and faster compared to the available SharePoint tools like SharePoint Designer ....etc, but what prevents us to use these 3rd party tools is the **cost** factor!

**What is the learning curve for such a solution?**

This will depend on which tool you will use. but in general, most of these tools has its own official site, user guide, tutorials, and learning videos as well as a discussion forum like StackExchange to help you to report your problems.

> **Note:** You should be aware of the technical questions on problems encountered using commercial 3rd-party software or plugins are
>   off-topic and will be closed in **SharePoint.StackExchange.com** as
>   they can be more easily answered by the specific vendor's support
>   team.

Comment: Thank you again Mohamed. Feel free to close it. However for the voter's ears, I did not refer to any particular solution in general but asked about whether key knowledge of SharePoint Designer and InfoPath would help  learning and be advantageous if one were to use a third party tool despite the assist it would lend.

Comment: You are welcome @MikeRooker, BTW, I don't talk about this question, I talk about *the technical questions on problems encountered using commercial 3rd-party software or plugins*.  so I don't close it moreover I answered it :), Actually, I would like to help all based on my humble knowledge whatever the type of question as long as it belongs to SharePoint, but it's the StackExchange a policy that we should follow and apply it :) Have a nice day bro!